# Images of alert window using XML file works in one Activity but in other one not

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I use xml file as popup. I use the same xml for all Activities.

It works fine if I call it from activity1 but if I call it **from activity2**, the images will not be displayed !

all other things work, only the images stay invisible!

The Images have OnClick methode, if I click on the Invisible images, the OnClick methode **works fine** , everything work fine **except the visibility of the images**

here is my code :

```
    public void ShowPopUp() {

        final Context context = this;
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_xml_layout);
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.my_xml_window_title));

 TextView txt_name=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);

txt_name=.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(main1.this, main2.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

dialog.show();
    }
```

**XML :**

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="left|center">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/imageview_1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView_1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <TextView
            android:text="name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView_name"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/imageview_1b"
            android:id="@+id/imageView_1b"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>
- - -
```

I call the alert window from map activity :

[<<<<< ScreenShot >>>>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayVz4.jpg)

Comment: How are you calling the method ShowPopUp() in the Activity2?

Comment: Hi, In Activity1 I call the methode from menu-Icon.via OnClick-Methode (works fine).   In Activity2 I call the methode from a normal Button.OnClick. Texts and Background colors will be displayed but the Images not